# How to express statement in $\mathcal{L}_A$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The statement,

"Zero is less than the successor of any number".

---

To my understanding, we express this with in $\mathcal{L}
_A$ using a constant ($\textbf{0}$), a function ($\textbf{S}$), addition (+), multiplication (*), and relation symbol (<).

I am confused a bit with the syntax of First-Order Logic.

My attempt:

$<0S0$

---

Does this seem correct? I believe I am representing "the successor of any number" incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Polish notation; for what it's worth, this is not the common notation these days.

What you've written says in plain English

> $0$ is less than the successor of $0$.

This is not what you want; you want to say

> $0$ is less than the successor of *any number*.

To do this, you're going to need to use a quantifier:

> **For every** $x$, $0$ is less than the successor of $x$.

In symbols (and using your notation), this is $$\forall x(<0Sx).$$

More commonly this would be written as $$\forall x(0<S(x)).$$ Note the extra parentheses ("$S(0)$" instead of "$S0$") and the infix notation for "$<$." One virtue of this is that it flows a bit more naturally when read aloud: "For every $x$, $0$ is less than the successor of $x$" rather than "For every $x$, is less than ($0$, successor $x$)." Obviously this is ultimately subjective, but I think it's worth pointing out the difference.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going for. Yes, thank you so much.. Is this often called "prefix" notation as well?

Comment: Secondly, when stated "use official syntax with prefix notation for terms and atomic formulas," what does that exactly entail? Specifically, 'atomic formulas'

Comment: @1011011010010100011 I suspect "prefix notation" is indeed another name for what you're writing. As to what "official syntax" means here, that will depend on your source. An "atomic formula" is a formula with no proper subformulas: "$<0S0$" is atomic, but "$\forall x(<0S0)$" is not since it has the subformula "$<0S0$" in it. An atomic formula has one of the following two forms: either it's of the form $R(t)$ for $R$ a relation symbol in the language and $t$ an appropriate-length (e.g. if $R$ is ternary, $t$ has length $3$) tuple of terms, or it's of the form $t_1=t_2$ for terms $t_1, t_2$.

Comment: Some authors also consider the *negation* of an atomic formula to be atomic, but I think this is pretty rare.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall x : 0 < Sx$$

It common for $a < b$ to be an abbreviation for $a \le b \land \lnot (a = b)$

$$\forall x : 0 \le Sx \land 0 \ne Sx$$

because $a \le b$ can then be an abbreviation for $\exists c . a + c = b$ :

$$\forall x . \exists y. 0 + y = Sx \land \lnot (0 = Sx)$$